# WCF Data Services and non-primitive types

Tags: wcf-data-services

I am trying to create a WCF dataservice for an Oracle database. I'm using the Oracle entity framework adapter and creating entities for all the views (its a read only service). The problem that I am encountering is that DateTimeOffset is not a supported primitive type.

OK, I've googled a fair bit and this is not an unknown problem but I can't find an answer! I can't edit the views to change the type returned as its a proprietary database. Some people have mentioned using RegisterKnownType(typeof(DateTimeOffset)) but this doesn't work. Other people have said I need to serialise the data but don't explain how.

Does anyone have a step by step solution as to how to get unsupported primitive types returned by WCF data services?

Answer (score 0):

Fom [Data Contract Known Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730167.aspx):

> Unlike other primitive types, the DateTimeOffset structure is not a
>   known type by default, so it must be manually added to the list of
>   known types.

This document as well as [KnownTypeAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.knowntypeattribute.aspx) describe how to add to the list of known types.

[Open Data Protocol by Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff478141.aspx) also mentions the DateTimeOffset type.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [Best work around to fix DateTimeOffset over WCF Data Service issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3700777/best-work-around-to-fix-datetimeoffset-over-wcf-data-service-issue)

> It's a bit of a hack using reflection, but putting the following in the application start up (I used [WebActivator](http://nuget.org/packages/WebActivator)) has so far worked for me using October 2011 CTP.

```cs
var primitiveResourceTypeMapType = typeof(ResourceType).Assembly.GetType("System.Data.Services.Providers.PrimitiveResourceTypeMap");
Debug.Assert(primitiveResourceTypeMapType != null);
var builtInTypesMappingField = primitiveResourceTypeMapType.GetField("builtInTypesMapping", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static);
Debug.Assert(builtInTypesMappingField != null);

var existingMap = ((KeyValuePair<Type, string>[])builtInTypesMappingField.GetValue(null)).ToList();
existingMap.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(DateTimeOffset), "Edm.DateTimeOffset"));
existingMap.Add(new KeyValuePair<Type, string>(typeof(DateTimeOffset?), "Edm.DateTimeOffset"));
builtInTypesMappingField.SetValue(null, existingMap.ToArray());
```